# Does a list of the non-letter ASCII symbol macros exist?

Tags: macros

Many symbols of the ASCII character set are assigned some special role in TeX (e.g. `&`, `%`, …). And many are also assigned a single-symbol macro (e.g. `\%`, `\,`, …). I was wondering whether a list of those non-letter and non-digit ASCII symbols exists, for which a macro exists.

Naturally, I could type them all out in a document, but something tells me that that will turn into more work than expected because it could generate a large number of errors (`undefined control sequence`). I was also unable to find such a list either here on TeX.SE or elsewhere.

Bonus points for including those symbols from the Latin-1 extension (excluding all diacritic-modified letters).

Because I realise that packages can (and will) define practically everything, there is no need to consider any when putting together this list. If you want to add what a few common packages do with certain symbols, feel free.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\ifx\^^@\undefined\else
0: \string\^^@=\meaning\^^@\par
\fi
\count0=1
\loop
\ifnum\catcode\count0=11
\else
{\lccode`a=\count0
\lowercase{
\ifcsname a\endcsname
\the\count0:
\expandafter\string\csname a\endcsname=%
\expandafter\meaning\csname a\endcsname\par
\fi}%
}%
\fi
\ifnum\count0<255
\advance\count0 1
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the generated list. Also it was new to me, that the uppercase Greek letter psi is an ASCII letter at position 9 ;-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes all the uppercase greek is squeezed into the control character range in OT1 (Gamma at position 0 used to break some pdf readers:-)

Answer (score 9):

Translation of David's [list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338558/16967):

- 9/`\^^I` (horizontal tabulator): explicit space as `\␣`
- 13/`\^^M` (carriage return): explicit space as `\␣`
- 32/`\␣` (backslash, space): set an explicit space
- 33/`\!`: a negative thin space in math mode
- 34/`\"`: diaeresis accent in text mode
- 35/`\#`: hash sign in text mode
- 36/`\$`: dollar in text or math mode
- 37/`\%`: percent sign in text mode
- 38/`\&`: ampersand in text mode
- 39/`\'`: acute accent in text mode
- 40/`\(`: begin inline math
- 41/`\)`: end inline math
- 42/`\*`: a line break point between factors of a product; if there is a line break, then the previous line ends with a thin space followed by a multiplication sign (×).
- 44/`\,`: thin space in math mode
- 45/`\-`: explicit hyphenation point with hyphen if hyphenated and without otherwise
- 46/`\.`: dot accent in text mode
- 47/`\/`: space for italic correction
- 58/`\:`: medium space in math mode
- 59/`\;`: thick space in math mode
- 61/`\=`: macron accent in text mode, or in environment `tabbing`: set tabulator
- 62/`\>`: medium space in math, or in environment `tabbing`: advance to next tabulator stop
- 64/`\@`: sets the space factor to 1000, typical usage is after abbreviation periods following lowercase letters, e.g.: `Mr.\@ John Doe`
- 91/`\[`: begin unnumbered display math
- 92/`\\`: line end/new line
- 93/`\]`: end unnumbered display math
- 94/`\^`: circumflex accent in text mode
- 95/`\_`: underscore in math and text mode
- 96/`` \` ``: grave accent in text mode
- 123/`\{`: left curly brace in math mode
- 124/`\|`: vertical line as delimiter in math mode
- 125/`\}`: right curly brace in math mode
- 126/`\~`: tilde accent in text mode